# Animated objects as particles - Is there a way to tell them when to start their animations?

Tags: animation, particles

I have this issue where I have an object with an animated material (also rigged meshes in another case), and using it as a hair type particle on a mesh. The problem is that all the particles animate at the exact same time, that is when the actual instanced object does. I’d like to be able to control when these particles start their animations. In my particular case I have a rectangular mesh, and I’d like to start the animation of the particles in the center where the object’s origin is, and gradually move out in a circle gradient. I kinda stuck here and really don't know how to solve this issue, so if you know any type of solution or approach to this issue please let me know!

Thanks!

Edit: added particle settings
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you will have to make a gradient texture which starts from white and slowly reaches to black with circle emerging from its centre(can be easily achieved by using a color ramp.) Then you will have to unwrap the face you want to apply particles on and place it in centre of unwrap grid and then apply the texture in length of particles under textures tab.
For editing the materials you will have to use only one object to be rendered as hair instead of a collection( if you want variety of hairs you can add displacement modifier and change it to local for random results). After this you can go into material tab and animate the material(press I while hovering over your mouse on color). Later on in animation you can add  random node in material or use multiple particle systems if you want to keep all the colours still there.

Comment: Added it to the OP, all collapsed options are as default, I just rotated it 90° in the rotation menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not exactly sure how this method will allow me to adjust when the actual animation of the material of the instanced object will play. As I see this, it will just start emitting the particles in the middle and move out in a circle, but all the animations will still play at the same time. Anyway, here's a simplified .blend file: http://www.mediafire.com/file/uwk1vlqgdcjdcx1/particle_animation.blend/file
Maybe your method will work, I don't know.

Comment: I will return to you soon

Comment: I actually got it to work as you suggested, and that part works great, but the main issue of the animated materials playing all at once still stands.

Comment: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes Try this addon